# Catching Mixed content error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, mixed-content

I'm trying to detect an XHR failing on mixed content. It looks like different browsers have different implementations:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
try {
  xhr.open('http://otherdomain/');
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err); // IE10 hits this one
}
try {
  xhr.send(); // Chrome fails here, but doesn't throw an error
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err); // No browser I've tried hits this one
}
```

I don't want to use autodetection (`xhr.open('//otherdomain')`), since the target might not support http, or https. I simply want to know the call failed, so I can show an error in my page. Is it possible to handle this correctly for all browsers?

Comment: Coincidentally having the same issue.  I'll let you know if I figure anything out.

Comment: @JuniorIncanter I haven't solved it per sé, but worked around the issue by adding a timeout to my future, and assuming this is the error if it doesn't complete.

Comment: That's the best I've come up with as well, but it still feels like a sloppy band-aid.

Comment: Anything more elegant than a timeout yet?

Comment: @Philip I haven't found another way, no. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to handle this error with javascript unfortunately. It is a security restriction enforced by the browser and thrown on a lower level. I have tried so many different methods, including the use of extensions but nothing worked except a timeout handler to be honest.